# B+ Trees internal nodes

Tags: data-structures, tree, binary-tree, abstract-syntax-tree, b-tree

I was working through a textbook and got stuck on this question:

"Consider a B+ Tree where each leaf block can contain a maximum of 3 records, each internal block can contain a maximum of 3 keys, all record blocks in the tree are fully occupied with 3 records each and the records have key values: 5,10,15,..., and there are 4 record blocks in the file"

Question: "Draw this tree in a single diagram"

So far I've added all the records in the leaf level, there's 4 blocks with 3 keys so 12 values total, so my leaf level has all multiples of 5 from 5 to 60. I'm now stuck on what to add on the level above it (internal block).

Comment: There are many ways to depict a B+ tree. Can you link to the text book?

Comment: Here's an example of a B+ tree: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TPhn.png and here's the question: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivKTi.png

Answer (score 1):

You have already done the right thing for the leaf level. There is only one internal block needed, which will have 4 pointers to those leaf blocks, and 3 keys. Those 3 keys are keys that typically are copies from the least keys in the blocks below that block. No key of the *first* block is repeated in that internal block, only of the other blocks.

One way of illustrating this structure, is like this:

[image]

Often the leaf blocks are linked together, in a singly or doubly linked list, although this is not a strict requirement for B+ trees. I have not depicted this above.

Comment: Thanks. You used 20, 35 and 50 for the above block. Are those the only possible nodes to be used in that position? Or could i use, 19, 34 and 48?

Comment: Also what program did you use to make that B+ Tree

Comment: They could indeed be any separating value (between the max of the previous child block and the min of the next), but when a B+tree is built gradually by inserting key by key, it follows naturally (from most common algorithms) to use the keys I have used. I just drew the boxes in a spreadsheet, took a screen shot and added the connecting lines in paint ;-)